# Debounce in Javascript

Tags: javascript, debouncing

I am currently learning debounce in Javascript and I came across two ways of writing debounce functions that works the same. One is a lot simpler like regular function, the other one is the complicated one that everyone seems to use.

###### Version 1:

**@index.html**

```html
<input type="text" oninput="betterFunction()">
```

**@script.js**

```js
function getData() {
  console.log('Data Fetched')
}

function debounce(callback, delay) {
  let timer
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
    }, delay)
  }
}

const betterFunction = debounce(getData, 1000)
```

---

##### Version 2:

**@index.html**

```html
<input type="text" oninput="debounce()">
```

**@script.js**

```js
let timer

function debounce() {
  clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Data Fetched');
  }, 1000)
}
```

What is the difference between these two ways of debouncing if they both gives the same result?
PS: I am surprised that I have never seen anyone use the 'version 2', ofcourse something must me wrong. Could anybody explain the differences please?

Comment: One is parameterized (i.e., you can specify the delay and the callback at invocation) and the other isn't. But as you've already acknowledged, the result is the same.

Comment: With the second version, if you want to debounce multiple inputs, you'll need to define a separate `debounce()` function for each of them. With the first version you can reuse the same function.

Comment: This can be use as well right, for multiple inputs?
<input type="text" oninput="debounce(()=>{//code}, 1000)">
    let timer
    function debounce(cb, delay) {
         clearTimeout(timer)
         timer = setTimeout(() => {
              cb();
         }, delay)
    }

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Debounce function is a javascript programming pattern for delaying execution of a function, your Version 1 is the commonly accepted pattern for implementing a debounce feature because its better than Version 2 for the reasons listed by MR. Polywhirl.

The pattern is actually making use of a javascript feature called a `closure`, which allows inner function (the function being returned by debounce) to access their outer scope (specifically in this case, the declared variable `timer`).

You can read about closures in detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to gain further understanding why version 1 is the preferred version, but this [explanation/example of closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) might be easier to grasp at first.

Comment: I came across closures while learning debounce and I understood that the returned function has the access to the state of its lexical environment. But my actual question is do we even need a closure for this, since we can literally define the 'timer' outside the function as well.

Comment: Thankyou for providing me those links. The counter dilemma example pretty much cleared most of my confusions.

Answer (score 12):

Version 1 is better, because it:

- encapsulates the `timer` (timeout ID) within the scope of—the lifetime of—the function call
- eliminates nasty global variables which could accidentally be modified outside or within another function
- most of all, it is reusable

#### An even-better debounce

[Josh W Comeau](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/javascript/debounce/) has an informative article covering debounce.

Here is his (modified) minimal version:

```js
const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
  let timeoutId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

**Note:** I replaced the `callback.apply(null, args)` with the more succinct `callback(...args)`

#### Usage

```js
const handleMouseMove = debounce((mouseEvent) => {
  // Do stuff with the event!
}, 250);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);    // Add listener
document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove); // Remove listener
```

#### Snippet

In the snippet below, points are drawn every time the user stops moving the mouse after 250ms. Each point is auto-removed after 2 seconds.

```js
const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
  let timeoutId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);
    }, wait);
  };
}

const createPoint = (x, y, color) => {
  const point = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), { className: 'point' });
  Object.assign(point.style, { top: `${y - 2}px`, left: `${x - 2}px`, background: color });
  document.body.append(point);
  return point;
};

// Log mouse coordinates when user stops moving mouse after 250ms
const handleMouseMove = debounce(({ clientX: x, clientY: y }) => {
  console.log(`Creating MOVE point at: (${x}, ${y})`);
  const point = createPoint(x, y, 'white');
  // Auto-remove after 1 second
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Removing MOVE point at: (${x}, ${y})`);
    point.remove();
  }, 2000);
}, 250);

// Log mouse coordinates when user stops clicking 250ms
const handleClick = debounce(({ clientX: x, clientY: y }) => {
  console.log(`Creating CLICK point at: (${x}, ${y})`);
  const point = createPoint(x, y, 'red');
  // Auto-remove after 1 second
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Removing CLICK point at: (${x}, ${y})`);
    point.remove();
  }, 2000);
}, 250);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5em !important; }
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { background: #222; position: relative; }
.point { position: absolute; width: 4px; height: 4px; border-radius: 50%; background: #FFF; }
```

Comment: Thankyou for this wonderful explanation. I went through the link you provided, it was really helpful. However the only doubt now I have is:
The outer function that encapsulates the timer variable....is only run once at the beginning, afterwards only the returned function is called. Am I right?

Comment: @VoodooChild when you wrap a function in `debounce`, you are essentially binding your own local `timeoutId` to that function. The function that gets returned is the actual function that you pass to the event handler. Whenever the callback fires, it has a reference to that bound `timeoutId` for the lifetime of the outer function's existence. A function that returns a function, when called, is a function. The `debounce` is basically a factory that returns a super-function that has its own bound scope. It's still a function at the end of the day.

Comment: Thankyou once again, I am grateful for your effort.

Answer (score -1):

This is optimal way to debounce methor. Realno clear old SetInterval

```html
export default (function () {
    let time;
    return function(callback, delay){
        return (...args) => {
            if(time){
                clearTimeout(time)
            }
            time = setTimeout(() => {
                callback(...args)
            }, delay);
        }
    } 
})()
```