# Input delay if it starting function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple app. In my app I have an input and js function that performed if I write char in input. (every char).
Function wants a lot of time, may be 2 or 3 seconds it is ok. But I have a delay in input.
I make my function async and tryed this:

```
async function myFunction()  {
     ...//some long time job.
}

myInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
     myFunction().then(res => {
           //some job after function
     })
})
```

but I have a delay again. I'd like to see text in input straightaway.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Call `myFunction` in `then` callback.

Comment: If `myFunction` is doing something CPU-bound that blocks the UI for a few seconds, you might consider looking into Web Workers to offload that process to another browser thread.

Comment: You may want to use a debounce function instead of running the code on every key press [Debounce in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988682/debounce-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This How I will Do It.

```
let timer = null;
async function my function(){
            
}
    
        myinput.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
            clear timeout(timer)
            timer = setTimeout(()=>{
              myfunction().then(()=>{
              // do something
              })
            }, 300)
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a JavaScript function that performs a long task every time a character is entered in the input field, which seems to be causing a delay in input processing. Even when using an asynchronous function, calling `myFunction` every time an input event occurs can slow down the input handling. To solve this, you should use Debouncing. Debouncing is a technique where, instead of immediately executing the function every time an input event occurs, it waits until the user stops typing and then executes the function. Try debounce with the example code below.

```
   let timeout;
    
    function debounce(func, wait) {
        return function(...args) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, args), wait);
        };
    }
    
    async function myFunction() {
        // ...
    }
    
    const debouncedMyFunction = debounce(() => {
        myFunction().then(res => {
            // ....
        });
    }, 300);
    
    myInput.addEventListener('input', debouncedMyFunction);
```