# Responsive auto fit font size relative to container height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Because there is no auto font size feature in CSS, I'm trying to create some code that will compensate this function, it works like this:
When the inner elements of the container are overflow the container height, the font size reduces by -1px each iteration until its stops being overflow.

```js
document.addEventListener(
  'DOMContentLoaded',
  function() {
    jQuery
      (
        function($) {
          function GetResponsiveValue() {
            return parseFloat($('body').css('--responsive-value'));
          }

          function SetResponsiveZoomValue(value) {
            $('body').css('--responsive-value', value + 'px'); // I dont know why this does not working here, its should work...
          }

          $('.responsive-container').each(
            function(i, value) {
              var timeout = 0;
              while (value.offsetHeight < value.scrollHeight && timeout <= 100) {
                var currentResponsiveValue = GetResponsiveValue();
                SetResponsiveZoomValue(currentResponsiveValue - 1);
                timeout++;
              } //Actually the font size changes after the iteration is complete, but its should be changed during the each iter.
            }
          );
        }
      );
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  --responsive-value: 10px;
}

.responsive-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.txt-1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: calc(20px + var(--responsive-value));
}

.txt-2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: calc(30px + var(--responsive-value));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="responsive-container">
    <span class="txt-1">
      Text size calc(20px + var(--responsive-value))
    </span>
    <span class="txt-2">
      Text size calc(30px + var(--responsive-value))
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

But, the problem is actually the font size changes after the iteration is complete, but its should be changed during the each iter.
How possible to make it work like "reduce font size -1px, check if now overflow, do it again, else stop"?

Comment: I'd suggest you look at [container query units](https://caniuse.com/css-container-query-units)

Comment: @Paulie_D In any case, it must be used in combination with JS as well, since this option in browsers only supports starting from 2022 versions.
So probably it must be used with this condition in the CSS code:
`@supports (font-size: 1cqi) {/*styles*/}`
And in a complementary way with code in JS which will compensate if the browser is not supports the container query units.

Comment: You really should update that jQuery version from 13 years ago for..well all the reasons.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss works the same

Comment: Not wishing to debate but the more recent versions have security issues addressed, are much faster and include additional features thus I would personally not classify "works the same" any  more than I would windows 2000 and Windows 10.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss meant in my question needs the versions works the same, in reall of course I use the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using CSS like `font-size: 1.25vw;` which gives you your font adjustment based on the initial value.  I just randomly chose an initial value for that font size.

Here I do that and **ONLY have the JavaScript to show the sizes** 250ms after the resize - to keep the event from triggering so much, I "debounce" it which I borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75988895/125981

```js
const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
  let timeoutId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
$('.responsive-container').on('resizeDebounced', function(event) {
  let currentSize = {
    txt1: $(this).find('.txt-1').css('font-size'),
    txt2: $(this).find('.txt-2').css('font-size'),
    container: $(event.target).css('font-size')
  };
  $(".show-place").text(JSON.stringify(currentSize));
});

const handleResize = debounce((mouseEvent) => {
  // Do stuff with the event!
  $('.responsive-container').trigger('resizeDebounced')
}, 250);
$(window).on('resize', debounce(handleResize, 250)).trigger('resize');
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  --responsive-value: 0.625em;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  row-gap: 5em;
}

.responsive-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 6.25em;
  width: 18.75em;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
}

.txt-1 {
  font-size: calc(1.25em + var(--responsive-value));
}

.txt-2 {
  font-size: calc(1.875em + var(--responsive-value));
}

.show-place {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="responsive-container">
    <div class="txt-1">
      Text size calc(1.25em + var(--responsive-value))
    </div>
    <div class="txt-2">
      Text size calc(1.875em + var(--responsive-value))
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="show-place"></div>
</body>
```

Similar snippet but no JavaScript to show a minimal implementation. Borders just to show what is where.  Flex added to keep things in the container in a column.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.responsive-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 18.75em;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 3vh;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.txt-1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  border: solid 1px #FFAF00;
}

.txt-2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="responsive-container">
    <div class="txt-1">
      Text size calc(1.25em + var(--responsive-value))
    </div>
    <div class="txt-2">
      Text size calc(1.875em + var(--responsive-value))
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The point is I need font adjusment to height.

Comment: Point here is the `font-size: 1.25vw;` - change to `font-size: 1.25vh;` if you prefer that base to measure from.  I changed the second example to use `font-size: 3vh;` instead as a reference.  Sometimes the board you saw is a choice if someone shows you how to use a saw and tape measure.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted a different solution I found elsewhere to this problem, it has served me well so maybe it will help you too.

You can play around with the buffer (maybe even negative values will work better for you) and ratio.

```
const fitFontSize = (
  text,
  maxFontSize,
  maxWidth,
) => {
  // approximate these by taking some representative samples
  const letterToWidthRatio = 0.82;
  const buffer = 4;

  let maxWordLength: number = text.length;

  const words = text.split(' ');
  if (words.length > 1) {
    const largestWord = words.reduce((a, b) => (a.length > b.length ? a : b));
    maxWordLength = largestWord.length;
  }

  const newFontSize = Math.min(
    maxFontSize,
    Math.ceil(maxWidth / (maxWordLength * letterToWidthRatio) + buffer)
  );

  if (!isNaN(newFontSize)) {
    return newFontSize;
  } else {
    return maxFontSize;
  }
};
```

Comment: Use it as function like this way `fitFontSize('string','2rem',txtContainer.offsetWidth)`?

Comment: And can you please explain what role play `maxWordLength`?
For example `Math.min(2rem, Math.ceil(300px / (10 * 0.82) + 4) = 41px)` => `min(2rem,41px)` what is this give?

Comment: `fitFontSize('string',16,txtContainer.offsetWidth)`

If you have a word with spaces, it takes the longest word so the text can wrap around multiple lines.